# python string on one line

Tags: python

My string is

```
a
b
c
d
```

I want to do this

```
a b c d
```

How?

Comment: Can you elaborate the question?

Comment: Can you show us the exact code you're currently looking and what you want it to do?

Comment: You have a string with new lines and you want to replace them with spaces?

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
s = "a\nb\nc\nd\n"
t = str.join(" ", s.splitlines())
```

Comment: what is faster by the way? your variant or user's 'somthing' variant?

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> txt="""a
b
c
d"""
>>> txt.replace("\n", " ")
'a b c d'
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, if you are trying to make it one line for HTML in order to send it in an email or to past it in a webpage you can do as follow:

```
str.replace('\n', '<br/>').replace('\r', '<br/>')
```

But is this is only to make it HTML.
I use it when when I'm using sendgrid API to pass email content in a get HTTP request.